# convert nu.XOM.Element to org.w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, xml, xom

Is it possible to convert `nu.XOM.Element` to `org.w3c.dom.Element`?

Am trying to construct XML using XOM APIs. But few of my legacy APIs expects `org.w3c.dom.Element`. So, I just want to know if I can convert.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `nu.xom.converters.DOMConverter` class, which provides a way of translating an entire XOM document into a corresponding DOM document, but you can't do it for individual elements, probably because a W3C `Element` can't exist without a parent `Document`.

Comment: I guess its the other way - DOMConverter converts w3c to XOM's.

Comment: @HanuAthena: It does both. There's one method that does XOM->DOM

Comment: Am sorry, am not able to figure out which method is that - http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/index.html?nu/xom/converters/DOMConverter.html

Comment: @HanuAthena: It's the fourth method. http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/converters/DOMConverter.html "Translates a XOM nu.xom.Document object into an equivalent org.w3c.dom.Document object."

Comment: See answer from @HanuAthena to see how to get the DOMImplementation instance, which is needed for the convert method call.

Answer (score 1):

XOM Document:

```
final nu.xom.Element root = new nu.xom.Element("root");
root.appendChild("Hello World!");
final nu.xom.Document xomDoc = new nu.xom.Document(root);
```

using DOMConverter:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
final DOMImplementation impl = builder.getDOMImplementation();
final Document w3cDoc= DOMConverter.convert(xomDoc, impl);
```

Comment: +1 because instructed how to get the current DOMImplementation, which is needed. I have no idea why XOM itself doesn't do this as the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static org.w3c.dom.Document xomToDom(Element elem) {
    try {
        elem = (Element)elem.copy();
        return
        DOMConverter.convert(new Document(elem), 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().getDOMImplementation());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```